# How should I charge my phone ( avoid fast charging)?

Tags: samsung, battery, charging, battery-life

I've recently got a new Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) running Android 6. It's great, but I'm not sure how to charge it properly.

By using the charger that came with the phone I get a notification saying "Fast Charging" and the phone heats up like crazy so it can shorten the life of the battery (although it does actually charge really quickly).

Alternatively I can use 3rd party chargers (none of which obviously suport fast charging), but many websites say it can harm the battery because they can be of really bad quality, so I don't like that option.

The best option I see is to charge it using my PC, but I can't have my PC everywhere I go and leaving it on overnight seems like an energy waste (no, my PC can't charge when it's off).

Disabling Fast Charging seems like a good idea, but since the Marshmalow update, the option is not in the settings anymore.

The text on the stock charger says:
Input: 100-240V 50-60 Hz 0.50 A 
Output: 9V DC 1.67A or 5V DC 2.0A

With all that in mind, what is the best way to charge my phone and do minimal damage to the battery in the long run?

Comment: Try keeping your phone in like tables or other hardened places (Not on a blanket,pillow,bed or any soft clothes). This helped me!

Comment: Upvoted for caring for your battery !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options :

- Power bank that doesn't support fast charging
- Normal `5 V 2.0 A` or `5 V 1.0 A` charger ( since fast chargers are backwards compatible )
- Using a USB hub between charging port and device
- Using a custom kernel that can lower charging current ( if device is rooted)
- Using a *Power only ( no data ) cable*

As confirmed by OP, the last option worked and they wanted to know **Is it safe?**. To answer that, we need to understand how such cables are designed

- A  *Power only ( no data ) cable* uses Pins  1 and 4 ( refer  [USB layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUSB.svg) )
- Which means pins **D + and D - are NOT used**. These pins are responsible for **negotiating** the power requirements -  (see [Overview of USB Charging](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5801) for more details )
- Li Ion batteries charge in stages ( see [Figure 1](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries) ),  which means that different voltage and current levels are required at each stage.  Stage 1 corresponds to < 20% and Stage 3 > 70-80 ℅ ( roughly - from experience )

Since D+ and D-  pins are not used to negotiate the power required for each stage, such a cable will provide a constant Voltage or Current at *all stages*, which is *not desirable*

From a theoretical point of view it should be OK,  if you are charging from 20 to 70-80% , but this may not be practically feasible. So, *it is safe* , IF, you ensure this charging limits

From a purist point of view ( as your question indicates), it is safer for battery to use the option of using a normal charger (that   negotiates requirements, while charging ) and that is the best way ! You can buy older OEM chargers that charge at 2A

Comment: Nope, nope, nope. You're assuming the charging electronics are in the charger; they're not. It's just a simple power supply, with selectable output voltages in the case of the fast charger. All the voltage and current regulation going into the actual cell is done in the phone. If not, well, what do you think happens if you hook 5V2A straight onto a Lithium cell?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: I know that. How do you read or interpret the answer to imply otherwise? But to make it clear the charger does house the IC that  is involved in fast charging mechanism. Else, if it had nothing , how does it charge as a normal charger a device not equipped with fast charging or how is it backward compatible?

Comment: Because you talk about the 'stages' of lithium battery charging, which are only seen by the buck regulator built into the phone. It's that regulator that adjusts the current/voltage supplied to the battery. Most chargers do no more negotiation than saying "I'm not a PC, draw as much current as you like until I turn off".

Comment: *Most chargers do no more negotiation than saying "I'm not a PC, draw as much current as you like until I turn off*-- Have a look at Table 4 and Fig 17 [here](http://goughlui.com/2016/05/29/review-teardown-anker-powercore-10050-a1310-qc2-0-power-bank/) for the negotiation done, which is way beyond *Am I a PC or not?*. Fact that it is a power bank does not make a material difference- is talking about fast charging and role of D  pins // As far as stages of charging are concerned, suggest you read the *Overview of USB charging* linked in the solution

Comment: You may also like to see the various stages and corresponding implementation in battery charger of 2008, when fast charging was not available. You can Google and download "APPLICATION NOTE S3F84K4
LI-ION BATTERY CHARGER" ( caps unintended , copy paste result). Not withstanding this, if you like you may share background for your conclusion. My solution is based on understanding which is supported but there well could be something I am missing. If you like you can point that out in a chat

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: Sorry, above comments were not tagged to you so I am not sure if you will get notified.

Comment: The vast majority of phones and chargers still do not support QC. It's still possible to charge quite 'fast' on a 5V-only charger. I assumed you were talking about slowing the charging down to the 500mA level found on a normal PC.

Comment: `Since D+ and D- pins are not used to negotiate the power required for each stage, such a cable will provide a constant Voltage or Current at all stages, which is not desirable`. It will not, because QC's negotiation only defines the voltage and *maximum* current, and standard USB negotiation only defines *maximum* current. The phone's charging IC will under no circumstances put more current into the battery than is safe, no matter what is negotiated. Again, that would give you a fire.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: 1. I said it is not *desirable* from the POV that each stage  requires different voltage and current,  which can't be negotiated in absence of D pins NOT from risk of drawing excessive current ( fire) . 2. Standard USB negotiates both voltage and current as you can see from the Samsung PDF I referred to ( I assume any standard OEM would do the same). May I suggest that you post a solution explaining in detail why you feel differently, since justification can be elaborate? Thanks

Comment: A standard USB charger will always output ~5V; varying of the voltage to the typical lithium cell voltage of ~3-4.2V (show me a phone with multiple cells...) is done inside the phone. The S3F84K4 is an IC that could be found (battery management is only one use case for that micro) in the device with the battery - you'll note that it talks about a 5V (the example given is literally USB) or 9V input, not the typical 100-240VAC input of a phone 'charger'. Also, an answer would not be the place to discuss another answer.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere:  I have presented my answer with reasons which are backed by documents or other evidence.  Your views have not been supported by any ( doesn't mean they are wrong). Asking you to post an answer is to study a substantiated different PoV.  If you don't care to post one, well, it's your choice. With courtesy, I have no wish to continue this chat further, since it doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: And I'm saying you're completely misinterpreting your supporting documents. I suggest you read [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130559/how-does-a-usb-2-0-wall-charger-negotiate-current-output) and the [USB battery charging specification](http://komposter.com.ua/documents/BC1.2_FINAL.pdf).

Comment: Also, in reference to one of your previous comments, the risk of over-drawing is not 'fire'. The output voltage should sag as it approaches maximum current/power.

Comment: Oops, dead link. [USB battery charging spec V1.2](kinetis.pl/sites/default/files/BC1.2_FINAL.pdf)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: My last comment on this chat 1.  Fire was in response to your previous comment, which suggested that. 2. Have a look at this please http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1225958.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50770/discussion-between-someone-somewhere-and-beeshyams).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting a Samsung travel adapter which outputs at only 5v.